# Enabling logs in a Web API

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I am new to the web development world and I would like to find a way to enable some sort of logs in my Web API project. I think that it will beneficial specially if I need to check any problem the user has in the future. I am using Visual Studio 2012

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried... anything?

Comment: ELMAH is very popular for logging exceptions. But you need to be more specific on what you want to achieve to actually get any decent answers.

Answer (score 2):

- [Tracing in ASP.NET Web
  API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/tracing-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [ASP.NET Web API
  Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/roncain/archive/2012/08/16/asp-net-web-api-tracing-preview.aspx)
- [Using NLog to provide custom tracing for your ASP.NET Web
  API](http://www.strathweb.com/2012/06/using-nlog-to-provide-custom-tracing-for-your-asp-net-web-api/)
- [Web API Contrib Log4Net
  adapter](https://github.com/WebApiContrib/WebApiContrib.Tracing.Log4Net)
- [Logging Exceptions with Elmah in an MVC 4 Web API
  Application](http://myadventuresincoding.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/c-logging-exceptions-with-elmah-in-an-mvc-4-web-api-application/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ELMAH](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah/) or [log4net](http://nuget.org/packages/log4net/) or [Enterprise Library Logger](http://nuget.org/packages/EnterpriseLibrary.Logging/). An easy way to get your solution up and running with any of these is by using the Nuget Package Installer.